# No SIM card - Unable to set up Network or use Internet on Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-7.0-nougat

I recently created an Android Virtual Device using the **Android N Atom x86 system image** with **Google Play**.

The problem is that I'm unable to set up a network or use internet due to **No SIM card** detected.

[image: No SIM Card notification]

Therefore, I cannot use none of the Google Play Apps or Services

[image]

The thing is that if I close this AVD and open another one with the **Android O Atom x86 system image** with **Google Play** installed, the network and internet works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday it was working fine for me but today it does not since installing Android O Play Store image, updating to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 and updating to Android Emulator 26.1.1. Did you do the same thing also before internet connectivity for Android N images stopped working?

EDIT: Confirmed emulator 26.1.1 has broken Android N network connectivity for me. I've added a comment to the existing issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62349956

Open up Android Studio 2.3.2, uninstall emulator 26.1.1 and install emulator 26.0.3, and it should be fine again.